# wx.SYS_COLOUR_WINDOW - Where do these system colours get set?

Tags: linux, gtk, wxpython, color-scheme

I'm looking at the source code for a wxpython application (I'm new to wx), and wanted to make a few changes to the colors used by the application - windows, tabs, etc.

What I found is that the developer had used things like:

```
sysTextColour = wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_WINDOWTEXT )
windowColor = wx.SystemSettings_GetColour(wx.SYS_COLOUR_WINDOW)
```

This of course makes a lot of sense, and my first preference would be to leave the code as-is, but instead change the system colors in such a way that all such toolkits will make used of them (wx, gtk, tk, etc).  If "all" is a bit ambitious, then at least have all "wx" applications make use of them.  My last preference would be to make changes to this code for changing the color theme.

I have no idea where to do this.

I'm running Linux, and wmii as the window manager - so unlike gnome/kde which probably give you a control panel to set these colors, wmii does not.

How would you recommend I go about making system-wide changes?

Answer (score 1):

The system colours get set in different ways depending on the system type. On some systems they're hard-coded in (to wxWigets), on others they're read from information provided by the system.

I'm not entirely sure which "version" (wxGTK, wxMac, wxUniversal...) wmii would use. Certainly on wxGTK they're read from GTK. You could try theming wmii (see http://wmii.suckless.org/themes). Hopefully someone else might have more info on how to do that.

In wxPython itself though, you can either take the options SystemSettings gives you, or use your own colours, but you can't set SystemSettings in wxPython. It's read-only.

Comment: Hi Cathy, the wmii themes are unfortunately mutually exclusive from the gtk themes - I've been meddling with wmii themes for some time, but the gtk stuff is still as grey as ever.  It's good to know that wxPython is readonly wrt system settings so I'll keep that in mind.  So now I'm back to square one - how do I change the system settings :(.